# Header and column mis aligned after implementing virtual scrollbar in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I have implemented scroll bar in the grid successfully, once I implement the scroll bar header and the column is misaligned since the scrollbar only push to left the column but not the header. Any advise, Thank you

Thank you

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<HH.BookModel>()

        .Name("Book")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:10px; width:495px" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {


            columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SessionCreateDate).EditorTemplateName);
            columns.Command(commands => commands.Destroy()).Width(100);



        })


        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Sortable()


        .Selectable()
        .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true))
        .ColumnMenu(c => c.Columns(false))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()//bind with Ajax instead server bind
            .PageSize(5)
            .ServerOperation(true)
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.BookID);

                })
                                     .Sort(sort => sort
                          .Add(x => x.Description).Descending())

            .Read(read => read.Action("GetBookData", "BookDetails").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
            .Destroy("DeleteBook", "BookDetails")
            )



    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the width of two of the columns. The third would occupy the rest of the space. This would also properly set the width of the header cells.

Comment: Do you know of an alternative solution?  This is too inflexible for me.

Answer (score 2):

I used a small code to let me control que header position. Hope that this helps a little. This is for Kendo Js Library.

```
function correctGridHeader() {
  if ($('#grid table.k-selectable').height() > $('#grid .k-grid-content').height()) {
    $('.k-grid .k-grid-header').css('padding-right', '17px');
  } else {
    $('.k-grid .k-grid-header').css('padding-right', '0px');
  }
}
```